# Is $\operatorname{lcm}(a,\gcd(b,c))=\gcd(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),\operatorname{lcm}(a,c))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

is $\operatorname{lcm}(a,\gcd(b,c))=\gcd(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),\operatorname{lcm}(a,c))$? it should be true for positive integers because the commutative algebra by Atiyah says addition, intersection on the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ is distributive. how should i solve it?

Comment: Could you define $a,b,c$?

Comment: Try it for $(a,b,c)=(2,3,5)$ - it fails as currently written.

Comment: sorry i edited my question

Comment: i am self studying, belive or not. i tried to compute both sides: left side: a*gcd(b,c)/gcd(a,b,c) and right side: gcd(ab/gcd(a,b),ac/gcd(a,c)) using lcm(a,b)=ab/gcd(a,b) then stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method that works in any gcd domain is to eliminate lcms using $\,{\rm lcm}(x,y) = xy/(x,y).\ $ Doing so and clearing denominators, then cancelling $a$ reduces it to

$$(a,b)(b,c)(c,a)\, =\, (a,b,c)(ab,bc,ca)$$

which is true since both sides $= (aab,aac,abb,abc,acc,bbc,bcc)$ by using ["gcd polynomial arithmetic"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242) (associate, commutative, distributive laws) to expand the products.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/147992/242) for the dual (and further detail).

Comment: okay now i see i had to proceed few steps further...... thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well its not elegant but let $a=\prod p_i^{a_i} $, $b=\prod p_i^ {b_i} $ and $c=\prod p_i^{ci} $ where $p_i $ are prime and the powers can be zero.

The power of the $p_i $ factor of $lcm (a,\gcd (b,c))$ is $T=\max (a_i,\min (b_i,c_i)) $

The power for $\gcd (lcm (a,b),lcm (a,c))$ is $S=\min (\max (a_i,b_i),\max (a_i,c_i)) $.

If $a_i$ is the least of the three then $T=\min (b_i,c_i) $ and $S=\min (b_i,c_i) $ so equality holds.

If $a_i $ is the most of the three $S=T=a_i $ and equality holds.

If $a_i $ is strictly in between, then $a_i > \min (b_i,c_i) $ so $T=a_i $. Likewise one of $b_i$ or $c_i $ is greater than $a_i $ and the other smaller.  So $a_i=$ one of the max pairs, but max of all three is the other max pair.  So $S $ is the min of the pairs is $a_i $.  So equality holds.

Comment: Good. But it can be shortened by noting that if $b\leq c$ then $\max (a,b)\leq \max (a,c)$ so $\min (\max (a,b),\max (a,c))=\max (a,b)$, and  also $\max (a,\min (b,c))=\max (a,b).$ Then interchange $ b $ with $ c.$

Comment: this is fairly neat. thanks.

Comment: I thought of that, but I only wanted to do three cases; not four with wolog.  I think my wording got obscure at the third point.

Comment: One shortcut consists in noting that both sides are symmetric in $b$ and $c$, so for a given $i$ you can assume $b_{i} \le c_{i}$.