# A relation between gcd and lcm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Let $a,b,c$ be non-zero integers . Let $(x,y)$ denote the gcd and $[x,y]$ denote the lcm of two non-zero integers . Then is it true that $ (a,[b,c])=[(a,b),(a,c)]$ ?

Comment: I believe so. Take a look at the prime factorization and what gcd and lcm do to the exponents of the primes.

Comment: In addition to the dupe I linked above see also See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2161615/242) for the dual.