# Formulas for lcm of three integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I know that both of the following formulas equal to $\text{lcm}(a,b,c)$, but how can we show that

$\dfrac{abc \cdot \gcd(a,b,c)}{\gcd(a,b) \cdot \gcd(a,c) \cdot  \gcd(b,c)} = \dfrac{abc }{\gcd(ab,ac,bc)}$ ?

Comment: Can you take for granted that $a\,b=\text{lcm}(a,b)\,\gcd(a,b)$ ?

Comment: By the way, you should simplify as $\gcd(a,b,c)\cdot\gcd(ab,ac,bc) = \gcd(a,b) \cdot \gcd(a,c) \cdot  \gcd(b,c)$.

Comment: @Righter Doesn't the setup in your comment only apply when $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ ?

Comment: Hint: Take $a=dpqx$, $b=dqry$, $c=drpz$, such that $d, p, q, r, x, y, z$ are all coprime.

Comment: @coffeemath Right, I made the change

Comment: @Righter In case one takes $d=1$ in your (new) version, it can be said only that $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime, as are $y,z,x$ and also the three pairs $(p,y),(q,z),(r,x)$ are each coprime. It can still be that the other possible pairs like $(p,z)$ may not be coprime.

Comment: @coffeemath Hmm.... is there any correct substitution of this type then?

Comment: @Righter I should have said $p,q,r$ are pairwise coprime in my comment. Other than that, one only keeps the coprime assumptions of my previous comment. [I was definitely in error in saying in previous comment that $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime.] Note that $d,$ the gcd of the triple $a,b,c$, need not have *any* coprime relation with any of the other six parameters $p,q,r,x,y,z.$  [This takes some argument as to why this can be done for unique values of the parameters for any positive $a,b,c.$]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147992/242) cancelling $\,abc\,$ then clearing denominators shows it is equivalent to

$$(a,b,c)(ab,bc,ca) = (a,b)(b,c)(c,a)\qquad$$

This equality is easy by [gcd "polynomial" arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242): expanding the products on both sides (apply gcd associative, commutative, distributive laws), shows both $= (aab,aac,abb,abc,acc,bbc,bcc)$.

Note: as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147992/242), it is equivalent to gcd distributes over lcm (or [vice-versa](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2161702/242)).

Comment: Also proved en passant [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2366155/242), along with the lcm equivalence.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

WLOG the highest exponents of prime $p$ that divides $a,b,c$ be $A,B,C$

WLOG $A\ge B\ge C\ge0$

So, the  highest exponents of prime $p$ that divides the numerator of the LHS will be $$A+B+C+C$$

For the denominator of the left hand side  the highest exponent $=B+C+C$

For the denominator of the right hand side the highest exponent  $$=B+C$$

The above will hold true for any prime that divides $abc$